# Why does Android studio will auto change color when I switch app in OS X?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Android studio will auto change color when I switch app or slide the touchpad on Mac. It is like the Android Studio's background color will get deeper or lighter.

Here is a [record](http://7xo5gx.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/1.gif) of a gif showing the problem.

Comment: same song and dance)